# Is there a way to access Workbook.AutoSaveOn from C#?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have Office 365 installed, and in VS2017 I have a C# solution with a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel that I created by adding a COM reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE.  I am able to automate Excel from this C# solution.  I would like to read the Workbook property AutoSaveOn, but Intellisense does not recognize it, and I get an error when I compile: Error    CS1061  'Workbook' does not contain a definition for 'AutoSaveOn' and no accessible extension method 'AutoSaveOn' accepting a first argument of type 'Workbook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Microsoft's Excel object model reference lists Workbook.AutoSaveOn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.autosaveon

I am able to access AutoSaveOn in a VBA macro.  Is there a way to read the property from C#?

Comment: Did you browse to `EXCEL.EXE`? Or did you choose it from the list of registered COM components? Also, you might try casting the workbook to `dynamic` and referencing the property; if it works, that means that it's only unavailable to Intellisense.

Comment: I first chose from the existing list, and when that did not work I browsed to the file.  Casting to dynamic worked.  Thanks!